# How i separate value from array in same line

Tags: php, arrays

From web scalping i get array like

```
1JANATAMF 7.20  -0.10    -1.37%
1STPRIMFMF 11.80  -0.10    -0.84%
AAMRATECH 32.80  0.40    1.23%
```

and many row.
I want to separate value like 1JANATAMF,7.20,-0.10,-1.37% or insert value to mysql data base by 1JANATAMF as a name and price as 7.20

How can i do this?

Comment: Please share your sample array, you gave string.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex:** `"@\s+@"` Here we are matching string on one or more spaces.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/777076)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$data=array(
    "1JANATAMF 7.20  -0.10    -1.37%",
    "1STPRIMFMF 11.80  -0.10    -0.84%",
    "AAMRATECH 32.80  0.40    1.23%" 
);
foreach($data as $value)
{
    print_r(preg_split("@\s+@", $value));
}
```

Comment: what does `@` delimiter do?

Comment: @YogeshMistry In your question there is an answer here `@` is the delimiter. regular expression should be in between any delimiter character set likewise i have used `@` . In `@\s+@` `@` is for delimiting regular expression and this `\s+` is the regular expression.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387420/cantt-parse-web-pages-with-php-simple-html-dom-parser)

Comment: @FindyMob I dont understand what you want ? Can you please explain.

Comment: $data=array(........here is already array result--- how i fixed it.)

Comment: @SahilGulati I am not the OP :D. Saw this for the first time, and couldn't find it here http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: @YogeshMistry Which thing you didnt find?

Comment: the `@` delimiter

Comment: There is line which say `Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~). ` . these delimiters are used often but you can use `@` but there is no issue,

Comment: Okay. I was just wondering how these delimiters affect the matching result of a regex.

Comment: no issues .. :) everything is a part of learning.

Comment: @SahilGulati  please see the link http://fb.pipschart.com/dsex.php and there i already a result but not done separate value.

Comment: @FindyMob Looking into your issue.

Comment: I hope you will accept both the answers